# Azure Bot Services Language Local Dialect

Tags: azure-bot-service

Does Azure Bot Services support local dialects of languages?

I have tried to log a technical support query through Azure, but our company does not currently have a support plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add translation to your bot](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/blog/2018/08/03/communicate-with-customers-in-their-language-using-multilingual-bots/) using Microsoft Translator API service with over 60 supported languages. Here is an [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples#advanced-bots) (go to: Advanced Bots > Multilingual bot). Bot Framework Composer also provides [multilingual support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language) for bot development in different languages.